# custom _id fields Django MongoDB MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

is it possible to use custom _id fields with Django and MongoEngine?
The problem is, if I try to save a string to the _id field it throws an Invalid ObjectId eror. What I want to do is using my own Id's. This never was a problem without using Django because I caught the DuplicateKeyError on creation if a given id was already existing (which was even necessary to tell the program, that this ID is already taken) 
Now it seems as if Django/MongoEngine won't even let me create a custom _id field :-/
Is there any way to work arround this without creating a second field for the ID and let the _id field create itself?

Greetings Codehai

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the parameter `primary_key=True` on a Field. This will make the target Field your _id Field.