# Is it possible to override "_id" field in MongoDB, when I'm using Django and Mongoengine?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I don't want to create a custom "id" field in MongoDB and make it my primary key.

But I want to override the "_id" field and make it an integer primary key so that every time I post a new document, it should have a integer id rather than ObectID.

Can it be possible by overriding some code in MongoEngine(PyMongo)? or this is the core functionality of MongoDB?

I've tried to insert documents directly in MongoDB database(without using Django), specifying the integer "_id" and it saves the document with no problem. However, when I try to query that particular document then it gives no result.

Same happens with Django, when I hit the API endpoint to see the list of documents it shows the one which has integer id.

But when I try to access that particular one, it says "no result found"

How can I deal with this, please advise.

Note: I'm new to both Django and MongoDB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom \_id fields Django MongoDB MongoEngine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370889/custom-id-fields-django-mongodb-mongoengine)

Comment: I don't want to create a custom _id field using some other name, I need to use the same "_id" name but with integer auto incremented values.

Comment: Auto-increment is a bad idea in a database designed for distributed deployment. That's why they recommend using ObjectID's.

Comment: without auto increment id fields I can still manage but is that possible which I mentioned here?

Comment: It's never going to be an integer _id field. At best you can manually force it to a String.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a document I used the unique=True attribute on a field to ensure I had such an ID.  I'm uncertain if this is your goal.

```
class Post(Document):
    p_id = StringField(min_length=64, max_length=64, required=True, unique=True)
```

I was using a 64character sha256 hexdigest as the p_id